# How to handle map function creating an object

Tags: typescript

I want my `data` object to be like:

```
{ email: "x", password: "x" }
```

**Logging** `data` brings me: `[ Promise { undefined }, Promise { <pending> } ]`

What do I have to change to get the desired result?

```
const controller = (modelName: string, fields: string[]) => {
    const createOne = (req: Request, res: Response) => {
        wrapper(req, res, async (prisma: PrismaClient) => {
            const data = fields.map(async (field) => {
                if (field in req.body) {
                    if (field === 'password') {
                        return { [field]: await hash(req.body[field], await genSalt(10)) }
                    }
                } else {
                    return { [field]: req.body[field] }
                }
            })
            console.log(data)
            // @ts-ignore
            return await prisma[modelName].create({ data })
        })
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: yes it does. thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`fields.map(async (field) => {/* ... */})` will return an array of promises. You can use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to await all of the values in one promise:

```ts
const mappedValues = await Promise.all(fields.map(async (field) => {/* ... */})
```

Comment: now there are 2 objects created in one array. I would like to get them merged in one object. how can I do this?

Comment: `const merged = Object.assign(...mappedValues)`

Comment: thank you. now it works just right.